# visual studio version for XP users support ssis

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

which is the latest visual studio version for Windows XP  that supports SQL Server Integration Services so I could run ssis projects?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 is the latest version that supports XP, but you will have to use have a computer running vista or later to install SQL 2012 Server though.

If you want to run everything on that XP machine then you must use visual studio 2008.

Strongly recommend upgrading your computer to Windows 7 or later for security and simplicity reasons.

Comment: I have re-read this answer 4 times and still don't really have any idea what it means.

Comment: Summary: Use Visual Studio 2008 or upgrade your computer.